# SBJson deserialization issues

Tags: ios, sbjson

Hi I'm having trouble with JSON deserialization.

I am using SBJson, the data is returned from a .net webservice.

This is the returned JSON (shortened)

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "result": [
        {
            "questionID": 21,
            "question": "What is the secret of eternal life?"
        },
        {
            "questionID": 20,
            "question": "What is the meaning of life?"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have got so far using the following code

```
-(void) dataLoaded:(NSData*)data {

    NSString* jsonString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    NSDictionary *jsonObject = [jsonString JSONValue];    

        NSLog(@"data : %@", [jsonObject valueForKey:@"result"]);
 }
```

The following line [jsonObject valueForKey:@"result"] returns the following data

```
(
        {
        question = "What is the secret of eternal life?";
        questionID = 21;
    },
        {
        question = "What is the meaning of life?";
        questionID = 20;
    }
)
```

how do i get that data into an array?

This is the first time i've used Json so i'm not totally sure what's going on.

Thanks
Mick

Answer (score 1):

You **are** getting an array back already...
You could use something like this to create a pointer to this array:

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSArray *myJsonArray = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"result"];
```

**EDIT (After some comments)**

Since you're logging the `[jsonObject valueForKey:@"result"]` and `NSLog` prints you what you have posted, its certain that the object is an `NSArray`.

You can count and log like this (notice the `%d`):

```
int c = [myJsonArray count];
NSLog("My array's count is: %d", c);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried that earlier by using the following 'code'NSArray* questions =  [jsonObject valueForKey:@"result"];'code' when i tried to get the array size the app bombed out.

Comment: What do you mean 'bombed out'? How did you try to get the size?

Comment: Sorry i meant crashed, i used the following line `int tmp = [questions count];`

Comment: ok and then crashed on that line or when you (maybe) tried to `NSLog` that value?

Comment: Hi Alladinian, just saw your edit. I'm not at my MAC at the moment (it's at home) but i'm not sure how your suggestion could work. isnt my `int tmp = [questions count];` the same as your `int c = [myJsonArray count];`? if my line crashed the app surely yours would too?

Comment: Yes it's the same. My doubt is not on that line. There could be 2 reasons to crash the app by trying to count the array: Either the Array is unallocated or you have tried to log an `int` with `%@`. Anyway try it when you can get your hands on.